# The least node that is greater than or equal to a given value in AVL

Tags: c, avl-tree

I am trying to implement a function in C that will find the smallest int that is greater than or equal to a given int in an AVL.  For example:

- if I have an AVL tree consisting of `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and I put in `6`, it should return `6`.
- if I have an AVL tree consisting of `1,2,3,4,6,7` and I put in `5`, it should return 6.
- if none are found, return -1.

I have found a case (there could be more) where this implementation fails.  If I have an AVL tree of `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and I input `3` it incorrectly returns `4`. This case occurs when the ROOT is bigger than the input. I am not sure how to fix this though. There could also be other cases — if you could let me know that would be great.

Here is my attempt:

```
int findLeastGreatest(Node *root, int input) {
    // Never found
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL && root->data < input)
        return -1;
    // Found
    if ((root->data >= input && root->left == NULL) ||
        (root->data >= input && root->left->data < input)) 
        return root->data;

    if (root->data <= input)     
        return findLeastGreatest(root->right, input);
    else        
        return findLeastGreatest(root->left, input);
}
```

Comment: I think the `|| (root->data >= input && root->left->data < input)` term is at least suspicious.  It isn't clear whether it's an attempt at optimization or a key part of the algorithm.  I wonder if the `if (root->data <= input)` condition should use `<` instead of `<=`?   If it's equal, you should not need to search further — which probably has ramifications.  If the search of the left tree finds nothing (returns `-1`) but the current node is bigger than the search item, you should return the current node, should you not?

Comment: Once you've found a node whose `data` is greater than the input, and the left child's `data` is less than the input, you need to check the rightmost leaf under that left child. So you can't just return `root->data` when `root->data >= input && root->left_data < input`

Comment: I think the algorithm works on any BST — binary search tree — and does not in any way rely on the tree being an AVL tree (which is a balanced form of a BST, and hence is a BST).

Answer (score 3):

Your function has problems: you are testing too many conditions together:

Here is a simpler approach:

- if the `root` is `NULL`, you should return `-1`;
- if the `root->data < input`, you should just recurse on the `root->right` node
- if `root->data == input` you should just return `input`.
- otherwise, you should recurse on the left node and return the result if found, otherwise return `root->data`.

Here is an implementation:

```
int findLeastGreatest(const Node *root, int input) {
    if (!root)
        return -1;
    if (root->data < input)
        return findLeastGreatest(root->right, input);
    if (root->data == input)
        return input;
    int value = findLeastGreatest(root->left, input);
    if (value == -1)
        return root->data;
    else
        return value;
}
```

If you are not required to produce a recursive version, here is a simpler version with a `while` loop:

```
int findLeastGreatest(const Node *root, int input) {
    int value = -1;
    while (root) {
        if (root->data < input) {
            root = root->right;
        } else {
            value = root->data;
            root = root->left;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the complexity is **O(log n)** because the function recurses at most once per call, so it follows a path in the tree which is by construction limited by `1 + log2 n` if the tree is properly balanced. If the tree is not balanced, the complexity can reach **O(n)**.

Comment: @chemslatt123: can you post the actual program code?

Comment: @chemslatt123: yes, but there might be other problems in the rest of the testing code :)

Comment: @chemslatt123: if you get a runtime error (a segmentation fault I presume) on this: `if (root->data < input)`, it means `root` is an invalid pointer. Since `root` cannot be a null pointer after the previous test, it seems your AVL tree construction code produced an invalid pointer somewhere in the tree.  Try and print the offending tree before calling `findLeastGreatest()`

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to write this function in a loop.  The algorithm in the pseudocode below should work.  The key idea is to not assign to `bound` unless the condition `(node.key >= key)` is true, in which case you must also traverse left to look for potentially smaller keys that satisfy the same condition.  Otherwise, traverse right to look for larger keys that might satisfy.

```
least_greatest(node, key):
  bound = -1
  while node != NULL:
    if node.key >= key:
      bound = node.key  # found a bound, but it might not be the least bound
      node = node.left  # look for a smaller key
    else:
      node = node.right  # look for larger keys
  return bound
```

P.S. this function is called `upper_bound` in the C++ STL, and I've also seen this called "least upper bound".

Comment: Good approach, UV, but would you mind translating from Python to C :)